# obeyspaces option for url package leads to option clash with Beamer

Tags: beamer, urls

I'm having some problems using the `path` command from the `url` package with my beamer slides. Providing the MWE below to `pdflatex` on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.10 produces the error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url`. Is there a recommended workaround?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url} % Preserve spaces in \path command

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Navigate to \path{C:\Program Files\}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of loading the `url` package yourself, you can just pass the `obeyspaces` to the package and let beamer load it for you.

In addition you need to use the `fragile` frame option.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
Navigate to \path{C:\Program Files\}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space in the path isn't there in your output.

Comment: @user4417 Upps, I'll investigate!

Comment: @user4417 I made  a stupid typo, please check again

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that Beamer loads the `url` package.

Comment: @user4417 Rule of thumb: beamer loads basically every package that can't run away fast enough :)